# Removing Map Layer from Silverlight Map Control

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, controls

After adding multiple layers, I want to remove map part from background to show my layers as schematric diagram. Is there any way possible to remove map from map control and show only layer diagrams.

Comment: AFAIK there is no 'Map' within the Silverlight namespace, so you'll need to give more details. What map is this? Some possible ones that spring to mind are ESRI, Bing, Telerik ...

Comment: Silverlight Map control in Silverlight toolkit. using Bing map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution. Changing Map mode to **MercatorMode** did the trick. So I added a button in navigation bar to change the mode. Which is something like this

```
ChangeMapModeButton schematicButton = new ChangeMapModeButton(new MercatorMode(), "Schematic", "Schematic View");
navControl.HorizontalPanel.Children.Add(schematicButton);
```

I'm not sure if this is the best method or not, but it did the trick.